# Click event of 'a' tag in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I need to trigger click events of "a" tags which are in "`deletable`" class. I saw some similar question in SO, but following code doesn't work for me. What i'm trying to do is to delete relevant `<li>` from `<ul>`.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.deletable').live("click", function () {
        alert("test"); // Debug
        // Code to remove this <li> from <ul>
     });
   });

<form ...>   
    <ul>
        <li>One<a href="#" class="deletable">Delete</a></li>
        <li>Two<a href="#" class="deletable">Delete</a></li>
        <li>Three<a href="#" class="deletable">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

I assume i'm using incorrect object hierarchy inside `$('...')` tag. But i don't have enough js/jquery/DOM knowladge to solve this problem. please help.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answers, but none of them works for me. Actually i'm adding `<li>`s dynamically. There maybe a problem. Please check,

`#sps` - a listbox
`#add` - a button
`#splist` - another listbox
`#remove` - a button

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#add').click(function(e) {
            var selectedOpts = $('#sps option:selected');
            if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
                alert("Nothing to move.");
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            $('#splist').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
            $('ul').append('<li>' + selectedOpts.text() + '<a href="#" class="deletable" id="id' + selectedOpts.val() + '">Remove</a>' + '</li>');
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $('#remove').click(function(e) {
            var selectedOpts = $('#splist option:selected');
            if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
                alert("Nothing to move.");
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            $(selectedOpts).remove();
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    });
```

Comment: put fiddle for your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.live()` method of jQuery has been deprecated. You can get similar functionality using `$('body')` and delegating to `.deletable` like I did in the following code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.deletable', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // this is the li that was clicked
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

The preventDefault method is used to keep the link from loading a new page should there be something targeted in the href attribute. If you keep the same HTML structure as you have in your example, then you can simply take the anchor element (`this`) and grab the parent, then remove it from the DOM.

It would be wise to, instead of using `$('body')`, target the container for the .deletable anchors, which, in this case, would be `$('ul')`. The function would look like this:

```
$('ul').on('click', '.deletable', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // this is the li that was clicked
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Using `$('body')` means that every event on the page would have to be filtered to see if it originated from a .deletable anchor. By scoping it to the `ul` preceding your li's, you limit the number of times your function is called increasing performance.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$('a.deletable')` selector ... this finds the `<a>` with class `deletable`.

u can go through the on delegate events too..  here is the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

try this

```
$('a.deletable').on("click",function(){
   alert("test"); // Debug
   // Code to remove this <li> from <ul>
   $(this).parent("li").remove();
});
```

if in case your `<li>` is added dynamically..

```
 $(document).on("click",'a.deletable',function(){ .... //even more better if u replace the document with closest elements to a.deletable ..like $(form)
```

`live()` is depricated..

Answer (score 1):

Some things first: if you're using jQuery 1.9, the `.live()` function is not anymore supported. Versions prior, that particular function is **deprecated** anyway, so you shouldn't really use it.

That being said, your syntax looks about correct. So I'm assuming that it's your hierarchy inside the handler function that's incorrect.

Something like this should work if you're trying to delete the parent `<li>`:

```
$('.deletable').on('click', function (e) {
    // since you're working with a link, it may be doing wonky default browser stuff
    // so disable that for now
    e.preventDefault();

    // then we delete the parent li here:
    $(this).parent('li').remove();
});
```

If you really want to make that into a delegate signature, something like this should work:

```
$('form').on('click', '.deletable', function (e) {
    // same banana
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.deletable').live("click",function(){
    alert("test"); // Debug
    $(this).parent('li').remove();
});
```